# run a command line entry in windows xp on login

Tags: authentication, windows-xp, registry, cmd

I am having issues with credentials being cached on a few of the laptops that area available to students at my university.

I have found that if i remove (remove not edit to `NULL`) a registry entry at

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\EAPOL\UserEapInfo
```

this solves the problem.

Im also pretty sure that this will delete the registry entry through the command line

```
REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\EAPOL\UserEapInfo /f
```

What I need to know is how to make this line run when the machine is logged into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Scheduled Task** maybe what you are looking for:

1. save your command into a .bat file somewhere
2. Go to Control Panel > Scheduled Tasks > Add Scheduled Task
3. config the scheduled task to run your .bat file, and schedule it to run "when I logon"

Comment: silly question but how do i save out a .bat file? is it something i can do from inside cmd?

Comment: It's just a simple text file.Open Notepad , type in your command line (REG DELETE HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\EAPOL\UserEapInfo /f
). Click "Save As" and save the file with ".bat" ending instead of ".txt".